# Volume mapping for jenkins in docker which has access to host docker

Tags: jenkins, docker

I'm now running jenkins in docker with the access to host's docker, so that I can run docker command without starting a slave on the same host.

But when I try to map some volume inside jenkins to the container I want to run(in host), the container will look for the volume from host, not from jenkins.

Now my jobs script becomes ugly, it has to specify a absolute path for the volume(on the host), and it can only be executed on the master now.

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Could you share your job script?

Comment: Have you tried using `--volumes-from jenkins` when starting the job container?

Comment: For jenkins:
docker run -d  -p 49001:49001 -p 50000:50000 -v /data/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home:rw --name jenkins -t jenkins

My script in jenkins jobs:
docker run -t --rm  -v /data/jenkins/workspace/Update_channel_id_for_zoho_creator:/automation  mouyigang/automation:1 ruby -Eutf-8 /automation/run.rb

This -v part used to be `pwd` to refer git cloned source code, which was executed be the slave.

Now I have to use the abs path of the host whereas my script get executed inside jenkins container. This script won't get executed in any other slave now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map using -v the same folder of host in the both containers.